# Define struct with one field in scheme

Tags: struct, scheme

I am working on a homework assignment for a class. The problem statement says to use the data definition:

```
(define-struct diff-exp exprs)
(define-struct mult-exp exprs)
;; An Expr is one of
;; -- Number
;; -- (make-diff-exp (cons Expr LOExpr))
;; -- (make-mult-exp (cons Expr LOExpr))
;; Interpretation: a diff-exp represents a difference,
;; and a mult-exp represents a multiplication.
;; A List of Exprs (LOExpr) is one of
;; -- empty
;; -- (cons Expr LOExpr)
```

However, when I have just that in the source, Dr. Scheme (Intermediate Student Language) says:

```
define-struct: expected a sequence of field names after the structure type name in `define-struct', but found something else
```

Is there something I am missing here or did my teacher give me an invalid data definition?

Comment: I suspect you should be definining `exprs` as a list of one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Anon suggested in the comment above, `define-struct` takes a list of fields; if you need only one, then use a list of one element.  Example code:

```
(define-struct diff-exp (exprs))

(let ((myexpr (make-diff-exp (list foo bar))))
  (diff-exp-exprs myexpr))
```

You can rifle through the many sundry features of `define-struct` [in the PLT Scheme documentation](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/define-struct.html).

Comment: That's all correct, except for saying "list of fields" which is confusing since there is no list involved.  There's only syntax that looks like (field1 field2 ...).

Comment: That's true, and I glossed over it because I didn't know if the poster understood the distinction between macros and functions yet, but it might be actually relevant to his problem if `exprs` is actually bound to a list in his code.  Hopefully he has found his way despite me.

Comment: My teacher eventually got back to me and said it was a typo on his part.